# Capturar retorno de um WebService

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, web-service, soap

Consegui, via PHP me conectar a um WebService via SOAP, porem não consigo caputrar os dados de retorno. Fiz um `var_dump` na variável de retorno, e o que é exibido na tela segue abaixo:

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'BuscaSMPResult' => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'MensagensErro' => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'RetornoMensagem' => 
            object(stdClass)[5]
              ...
      public 'TransacaoOk' => boolean false
      public 'SMP' => null
```

Como posso capturar esses dados?

**Edit**

Texto retornado ao usar `print_r` no lugar de`var_dump`:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [InsereSMPResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [MensagensErro] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [RetornoMensagem] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Codigo] => 1001
                            [Mensagem] => É necessário informar o Token
                        )

                )

            [TransacaoOk] => 
            [MensagensAviso] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

            [MensagensSucesso] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

            [AnoSMP] => 0
            [IdSMP] => 0
            [NumeroSMP] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: echo($response->InsereSMPResult->MensagensErro->RetornoMensagem->Codigo); //Assim não funciona?

Comment: Esta retornando um objeto, não seria algo assim:

Considerando que o retorno seja em **$data** querendo obter o valor de **Codigo**:

**$codigo = $data->InsereSMPResult->MensagensErro->RetornoMensagem->Codigo;**

Comment: @Everson retorna vazio

Comment: @Lucas Torres É necessário informar o Token

Answer (score 0):

Impresso com:

```
 $result = $data->InsereSMPResult->MensagensErro->RetornoMensagem['Codi‌​go']
```

Comment: Isso resolveu o problema?

Comment: Sim, na verdade era mais um erro de interpretação. Por mais que fosse um objeto, parece que o "Codigo" era um parâmetro, e não um objeto